# Power usage of ports of the Switch

Tags: lan, cisco-catalyst, switching

I have doubt regarding the swicthes of network.I want to know the power usage of the switches by changing the active number of ports. If I change the egress traffic ports(like port2 port3 etc.,)by taking the ingress port constant port1.Is this approach consume more power? or If I connect two or more sources and passing the traffic from ports 1-2 and ports 3-4 etc., will consume more power? Can you please explain this behaviour?

Comment: Are you asking about PoE or ordinary switching?

Comment: I am asking about Cisco 2950,2960 and 3560 which consists PoE I think.

Comment: In my case I am doing normal switching between sources and destinations and I want to know the power usage by variation of active number of ports.

Comment: The basic power usage of a switch is not really affected by the number of ports in use. PoE, on the other hand, does affect the power usage of a switch.

Comment: Are sure that the active number of ports doesnot affect the power usage of switch? As PoE states that the power considered for particular port right?

Comment: The basic power usage for a switch is so large in comparison to the very minimal usage on an active switch port that it is almost a rounding error. PoE can greatly affect the power used by the switch, depending on the watts drawn by the PoE devices, and the power spent over the cabling to deliver the power to the PoE devices. It is possible to draw so much power using PoE that you cannot use PoE on all the ports because the power supply cannot provide all the necessary power.

Comment: Thanks for your discussion on this. I am still unclear about this PoE and ports power usage.Anyway, I will search more and get some clarity on this.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see power consumption of PoE, you can use "show power inline" command which will display power usage per port, plus total power and available power.

Comment: I want profile the power consumption of Switches by taking the consideration of Number of active ports.

Comment: The switch's power consumption does not fluctuate with active/inactive ports.  If the switch power supply is 250W, then it will pull 250W no matter how many interfaces are active.  If you are running PoE, you can see the "power budget" by using "show power inline" command.

Comment: I am doing my research on Cisco 2950,2960 and 3560 switches by varying the load and also by varying the active number of ports of switch. So is this result in the power consumption with consideration of above parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Roughly, an active 1000BASE-T port (in modern equipment) will consume approximately 100 mW more than one without link. Without Energy-Efficient Ethernet (EEE), this applies to all port that are linked, regardless of whether there's traffic or not.

With EEE, inactive ports can power down to ca. 5-10% of their active power, a usual average value is 50%.

With 10GBASE-T, the active port value is closer to 1 W, so potential savings of EEE are larger.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring any form of PoE, standard Ethernet does draw a certain amount of power for each port that is connected (in an up state) whether that port is transmitting or not. IIRC, you can count on about 100-300mW of power per port with link.

If you want to reduce the power consumption, you need to remove the connection or disable the port. However in many devices, these ports will still consume at least some power even then.

Alternatively, newer devices are supporting 802.3az Energy Efficient Ethernet and/or "Green Ethernet" (non-standardized but reduces power usage in potentially several ways) can reduce the power usage of active Ethernet links by using one or more of several techniques like letting the transmitter "sleep" when there is no data to send, reducing power when shorter runs are detected or simply through more efficient electronic components.